# vb.net msaccess update, may i ask whats wrong, why it does not update my data base?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

I don't know what seems to be the problem, 
can anyone help?

I already installed all necessary thing to run the program.

```
Public Sub main1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles main1.Click
    scorestanding.Text = standingscore
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    dataFile = "Database\user.mdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim str As String

    str = "UPDATE login set[scorestand] = '" & scorestanding.Text & "'  Where [username] = '" & Label1.Text & "'"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)

    Try
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE login set[scorestand] = '" & scorestanding.Text & "'  Where [username] = '" & Label1.Text
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Me.Close()
    main.Show()
End Sub

    str = "UPDATE login set[scorestand] = '" & scorestanding.Text & "'  Where [username] = '" & Label1.Text & "'"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)

    Try
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE login set[scorestand] = '" & scorestanding.Text & "'  Where [username] = '" & Label1.Text
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Me.Close()
    main.Show()
End Sub
```

It does nt have any eror but it also does nothing.

Comment: Set breakpoints they are friendly and great. You need to step through and see where it breaks. I can tell you there's more than a few issues...

Comment: If no errors, it may be possible that the where condition was the failure point. Create a variable e.g. Dim Results As Integer = 0, then Results = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery. Check the value of Results, if -1 or 0 the where condition was not met while if one record was expected to be updated then 1 should had been returned. On a side note please consider using parameters rather than concatenating string for the query.